# Воспроизведение audio/l16 python

Tags: python, аудио, tts

Имеется ответ от сервера tts с `Content-type: audio/l16;rate=24000;channels=1;endianness=big-endian`

Необходимо воспроизвести полученное аудио с помощью Python 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение с помощью утилиты sox.

1. Устанавливаем: `apt install -y sox`
2. Сохраняем файл как audio.raw
3. Конвертируем в wav следующим кодом:

   ```
   import os
   os.system('sox -r 24000 -b 16 -e signed-integer -B -c 1 audio.raw audio.wav')
   ```
4. Воспроизводим. Пример с использованием библиотеки simpleaudio:

   ```
   import simpleaudio as sa
   audio_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('audio.wav')
   audio2_obj = audio_obj.play()
   audio2_obj.wait_done()
   ```